# Visual Studio Code cannot open source file "iostream"

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, computer-science, include-path

I am new to C++ and Visual Studio Code, so I'm not sure how to fix this issue. I've tried to go through the tutorial in *[Using Clang in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)*, but I can't seem to paste their "[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)" code without the *iostream*, *vector*, and *string* errors.

I've also seen posts on here indicating that I should change the *includePath* string array in configurations, but adding the path to my project folder doesn't seem to get rid of these errors. I'm at a loss here since everything I've seen so far still isn't working.

The code which causes these errors has been copy pasted directly from the tutorial above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

In the first three lines, I'm getting the errors `"cannot open source file {the included import's name}"`. The compiler states that:

> #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/Users/rjc/projects/helloworld/helloworld.cpp).C/C++(1696)

I added this line in my includePath as such (the configurations page states add one includePath per line, so I put these two statements on separate lines):

`${workspaceFolder}/**`
`/Users/rjc/projects/helloworld/`

Yet this did not reduce the number of errors. I'm not really sure what to do here, since the tutorial does not seem to be working for me.

I'm running [macOS 11.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur) with Clang version 12.0.0. Why do I have these issues?

Comment: Try replacing `<iostream>` with `"iostream"`...
There's a difference between `<header_file>` and `"header_file"`
Here's a lil something you will find useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Comment: Did you try to compile it directly? Invoke clang++ with your file as argument, if it works then it's VSCode issue, not a compiler issue.

Comment: I think the intuition is that `includePath` is for 'intellisense' only, it does not affect the compiler. Now why your compiler cannot find the header files is another issue. As Kalldr says the thing you should try is to use your compiler outside of VSCode to find out if it's a compiler issue or a VSCode issue.

Comment: @NovusEdge I replaced all three but the compiler is still returning the same errors. It keeps telling me to update my includePath

Comment: @rjc810 That advice is incorrect (except maybe as a diagnostic tool). `#include <iostream>` is correct code.

Comment: @john sorry I'm quite new to this, how should I try to compile it outside of vs code? should I just run clang++ helloworld.cpp inside terminal?

Comment: @rjc810 That would be a start, try that and report any error.

Comment: The compiler is returning 

helloworld.cpp:9:23: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "an...
                      ^
                      ;
helloworld.cpp:11:29: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (const string& word : msg)

Not sure where the first error is coming from, since this line (in full) is
```
vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};
```

Comment: @rjc810 Well that implies that from the command line the compiler can find the header files (since the errors you have are after that). So it seems to be a VSCode problem. I'm sorry but I don't know anything about VSCode on a Mac.

Comment: This page helped me to configure it properly using the CLang compiler https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your includePath only has `${workspaceFolder}`. You need to add the path to your system directory. Run this command and make sure all of the paths printed out are listed in your *c_cpp_properties.json* file: `gcc -v -E -x c++ -`

Comment: Open your terminal app and run the command above.

Comment: I copy pasted all the paths into the includePath array in properties.json, but I'm still getting the same errors. I have  "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1",
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include",
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include",
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include",
              "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"

Comment: update: deleting the workspaceFolder string seems to satisfy the compiler. I'm still getting an error from this line though. vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"}; Compiler is telling me that a semicolon is expected at the end of the declaration, but my array has a semicolon after it. Am I missing something trivial here? Thank you!

Comment: Try to install the 'Include Autocomplete' extension in vscode.

Comment: installed the extension. not sure why the code is giving me errors, since i copy pasted it directly off of the vscode tutorial. is it maybe a problem with my version of vscode?

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry. Did you install the 'C/C++' extension in vscode?

Comment: No worries! I installed it- but I'm still getting errors on this one line of code:
`vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};`

Comment: Faced the same problem Allen, and this method worked. Could you kindly elaborate on what this command actually does. Newbie here.

Comment: What if I don't have a c_cpp_properties.json? I can build and run but the sguigglies remain.

Answer (score 5):

as told above you should

- run this command in the terminal:  `gcc -v -E -x c++ -`
- then it shows you all the paths to include as shown in the image

[image]

- now open search for this file ***c_cpp_properties.json*** in vs code (by tapping `cntrl + p` in vscode)
- now open ***c_cpp_properties.json*** file and paste all the file paths I've marked *(which may be more or less in your case)* as shown in image

[image]

- and then you are ready to go!
- **HAPPY CODING!**

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, add the code or the text.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the compiler in the `compilerPath` setting exists and that it supports C++.

I saw these [stdlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#Header_files) include errors on a ([CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)) system that had [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) installed without C++ support. Installing the missing packaged fixed the errors in Visual Studio Code. Failing to compile a hello.cpp from the terminal made it clear my root problem was not in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change 3 times in the `c_cpp_properties.json` file.

1. "name": "Mac"
2. add "usr/include/linux" to the "includePath"
3. "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"

This solution is for Linux users only.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu I had different gcc/g++ versions installed.

Check your c++ version

```
c++ -v
```

Check directory `/usr/include/c++` and if it is missing the corresponding version (10/ or 11/ or 12/), install it `sudo apt install libstdc++-XX`. I had to install `libstdc++-12`

```
sudo apt install libstdc++-12
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working with mingw g++ compiler. I got this error too while I was runnning my program. I just changed the compiler path. It worked in my case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had a similar issue this week when starting a new cpp project - it turns out that when I had switched from Windows to Linux, midway through kicking off the project, I forgot to update all my paths in the tasks.json and  c_cpp_properties.json files (inside the .vscode directory), which were still using the Windows path standards (\ instead of /).
Once I fixed this, all was well.
Incidentally, I made my tasks.json an array of tasks and my c_cpp_properties.json an array of configurations as well, allowing me to add both windows compiler options as well as linux compiler options separately - on build I select which one to use.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, and I was trying anything to get it to work.

Then I realized that when I named the file I only named it *helloworld* instead of *helloworld.cpp* behind since this wasn't needed in the other IDEs I've been using.

Comment: But `<iostream>` is a __standard header__ not a user file.