# VSCode cannot detect C++ system files when clangd is enabled

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clangd

For example, if I include `<string>`, it will show an error saying `'string' file not found clang(pp_file_not_found)`:
[image: screenshot of the error message]

I am building the project into build folder. And use a .clangd file to specify the CompilationDatabase to where compile_commands.json is. This method is successful in my another PC(macOS). For VScode settings about clangd, I specified the `clangd.path`.

For this PC(Linux Ubuntu), I tried to add "-std=c++17" to 'clangd.fallbackflags'. But it still does not work.

When I use CMake to compile the whole project, it works well. Seems it is a VSCode issue or clangd issue.

Update: I found that if I use `#include <9/string>` instead of `#include <string>`, vscode can find the file, is that something about include path? However, I have never made changes to it. So I tried to update the include path by this method [Visual Studio Code cannot open source file "iostream"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65421161/visual-studio-code-cannot-open-source-file-iostream). Still does not work.

Comment: did you follow the project setup instructions for the clangd extension? (I.e. put a compile commands database file in the workspace root? see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/76214615/11107541)

Comment: Yes, I use CMake and use `set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)` to set. Also use .clangd file to specify the position of `compile_commands.json`. Also add "-std=c++17" to 'clangd.fallbackflags'. Still does not work.

Comment: okay, but is your build directory set to the source directory, then? (in-source build)?

Comment: Do you mean `{my_project_path}/build`? I did so.

Comment: if you're building to a subdirectory of the source directory, then that is not an in-source build, and you need to follow the instructions in the post which I linked you to.

Comment: Yes, I am building into build folder. However, I use a `.clangd` file to specify the `CompilationDatabase` to where compile_commands.json is. This method is successful in my another PC.

Comment: you should have specified that in your question post. Please edit your post to specify that.

Comment: VSC has a tab for Clangd logs. The logs show which compiler flags were inferred for each source file, and why. Look for your current filename there, check if the flags are right.

Comment: I find that if I use `#include <9/string>` instead of `#include <string>`, vscode can find the file, is that something about include path? However, I have never made changes to it.

Comment: I tried to update the include path by this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65421161/visual-studio-code-cannot-open-source-file-iostream It does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into a known issue affecting Ubuntu 22.04: https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1394.

You can read about the available workarounds in [this comment](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1394#issuecomment-1328676884), but this simplest one is to install `g++-12`.

---

If that's not the issue, my next suggestion is to read these parts of the clangd docs:

- https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#cant-find-standard-library-headers-map-stdioh-etc
- https://clangd.llvm.org/guides/system-headers#query-driver

and try `--query-driver` in particular.

---

If you're still not having any luck, please share [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs) for further diagnosis.